# Redirect HTTP paths to a different server and port

Tags: networking, browser, webserver, http

I have a home server that is running multiple applications.  I currently can access these services remotely, by using a specific port number.  Due to web filtering reasons, this will not work for me when I am using certain computers.  I'm looking for a way to "redirect" to a different port, while still using the address that I type in.  Also, subdomains will not work, I'll have to use folder paths.

For example:

```
URL that I type in       Path I actually access
http://example.com       http://example.com:80
http://example.com/plex  http://example.com:32400
http://example.com/php   http://example.com:8080
```

Please note, that the address bar must remain using the example.com/service type address, NOT the example.com:port address.  Also, not all services are web hosts.

Any easy/free way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Either frames (very simple) or reverse proxying (more complicated, but you can see more than just `http://example.com/plex` in your address bar) can achieve what you want.

As for RDP: You don’t type that in your browser. If you really want to, upload a saved RDP session. You can then download and open the file every time.

---

**Apache and mod_proxy**

Apache provides support for proxying via [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). The most basic example is something likes this:

```
ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

The [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive determines which path to pass to which upstream server. [`ProxyPassReverse`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) makes Apache rewrite some response headers to mask the upstream servers’s address.

As you may have noticed, there’s a major shortcoming to this: Nothing is rewritten inside the response page. So unless there are only relative links, this method might only work for a single request. Additional problems may arise if you “rename” parts of the URL. Ideally, the application you choose proxy requests to explicitly should support being used with a reverse proxy.

A basic example for your Plex setup would go something like this:

```
ProxyPass /plex http://localhost:32400/
ProxyPassReverse /plex http://localhost:32400/
```

**However**, [it would appear that Plex Media Server is rather uncooperative](https://forums.plex.tv/index.php/topic/38746-pms-behind-apache-proxy/) in this regard, so you may have to rethink your idea. Plain redirects are much easier to configure and are guaranteed to work without problems. You won’t get a nice URL in the address bar though.

Of course, you could also use nginx for reverse proxying, and it’ll probably be a whole lot faster.

Comment: Ah, yes, RDP was a bad example.  Tell me more about the reverse proxying?  It's important that the address bar stay example.com/service...  Would this occur?

Comment: @MikeChristiansen I’ve updated my answer. Basically, yes. In reality, you won’t have too much fun with it.